# ** WARNING: soft rlimits too low. Number of files is 256, should be at least 1000

Tags: mongodb, database, nosql

i ran on Mac OSX capitan and everytime i run mongo shell, this warning will pop up. i tried:

sudo ulimit -n 1024

ulimit -n 1024

it still doesn't work. any ideas?

Answer (score 13):

You should try to close your terminal and redo it. Or directly try it in your shell which runs mongodb.

1. Close the running MonogoDB
2. Run the following bash code:

   ```
   sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 65536 65536
   sudo launchctl limit maxproc 2048 2048
   ulimit -n 65536
   ulimit -u 2048
   ```
3. Close the terminal or bash and restart.
4. run `ulimit -n` in terminal to test if change successfully